# Three.js Shortcuts

Tags: javascript

I've written shortcuts for the Three.js library. This is mainly for my personal use. I'm not that good with remembering the complex name of the Three.js library, so these shortcuts are meant to make it easier. I'm looking for code efficiency and compactness, since I know compactness is a big concern for javascript files. The comments are all for myself, so even if they seem verbose, they help me remember how to use the functions. Thank you in advance for any suggestions/improvements.

```
/*
* Shortcuts for Three.js object creation
*/

/*
* Creates a scene with a sepcific background color
* Example Usage: 
*   var scene = createScene(0xffffff);
*/
function createScene(color) {
    let scene = new THREE.Scene();
    scene.background = new THREE.Color(color);
    return scene;
}

/*
* Creates a camera for the scene
* Example usage:
*   var camera = createCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
*/
function createCamera(fov, aspect, near, far) {
    let camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(fov, aspect, near, far);
}

/*
* Creates a cube with a mesh(color) and geometry
* Example Usage: 
*   var cube = createCube(7, 7, 7, 0x005500);
*/
function createCube(width, height, depth, c) {
    let geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(width, height, depth);
    let material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: c});
    let cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    return cube;
}

/*
* Creates a WebGLRenderer, with a given width and height
* Example Usage: 
*   var renderer = createRenderer(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
*   document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
*/
function createRenderer(width, height) {
    let renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setSize(width, height);
    return renderer;
}

/*
* Usage Example for all the functions:
*
*   var scene = createScene(0xffffff);
*   var camera = createCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
*   var renderer = createRenderer(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
*   document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
*   var cube = createCube(7, 7, 7, 0x005500);
*   scene.add(cube);
*
*   // User can write rest of implementation //
*/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Style points

- Why assign a variable when the reference is immediately dropped on returning from the function. In function `createCamera` the variable `let camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(fov, aspect, near, far);` is never used???
- Use `const` for variables that do not change.
- Name arguments when possible such that you can use object property shorthand to put them in an object. Eg you named color `col` and then create an object `{ color: col }` but if you named the argument `color` you could then create the same object as `{ color }`

### Building a framework

You will be better of putting all this functionality into an object, keeping the global namespace free of clutter and providing a framework that you can build upon as the needs arise.

### Example

```
const utils = {
    create: {
        material(color) { return new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color}) },
        camera(...args) { return new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(...args) },
        cube(width, height, depth, color) {
            return new THREE.Mesh(
                new THREE.BoxGeometry(width, height, depth), 
                utils3.create.material(color)
            );
        },
        scene(color) {
            const scene = new THREE.Scene();
            scene.background = new THREE.Color(color);
            return scene;
        },
        renderer(width, height) {
            const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
            renderer.setSize(width, height);
            return renderer;
        },
    }
};
```